# How do I get access to the Linkedin profile API?

Tags: linkedin-api

How do I get access to the Linkedin profile API? I want to fetch user URLs when they sign on to my site using the "Sign in with Linkedin" API. Linkedin granted me access to the Sign in with Linkedin API without any approvals, but I am not sure how to get access to the "Profile API".

I tried using the "Sign in with Linkedin" API, but I'm not sure if that can be used to get user profile URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vanity name of the member. The vanity name is represented as a string in the public profile URL: `www.linkedin.com/in/{vanityName}`.

[image]

The refernce to vanityName Link is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext).

More detail about the current permissions on LinkedIn can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access).

If you talk about a specific API, such as the profile API, it was given by LinkedIn in previous versions, but now it is not available. Currently, they are in development mode, and soon they will release, hopefully.

Feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access user data via backend api, you need the new Community Management API https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog/marketing/community-management-api

You will need a legally formed corporation and go through a vetting process.